# Bridged veth virtual network and routing

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I'm trying to connect three docker containers in a network and run OSPF between them. I'm using veth interfaces and a bridge, trying to follow [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/765078/579620). However, I think I'm misunderstanding how it works. The containers can ping each other, but don't consider each other in the same network.

To make the network, I'm only using one bridge, and 3 veth pairs. Each pair has one end on the bridge, and the other end in the container. Here is my configuration.

```
ip tuntap add tapm mode tap
ip link set dev tapm up

ip link add brm type bridge
ip link set brm up

ip link set tapm master brm

ip addr add 2001:db9:4::1/64 dev brm
```

The following is repeated three times, for each container (changing only the name of the veth pair, the addresses, and the namespace)

```
ip link add dev vn1 type veth peer name vn1br
ip link set dev vn1br up

ip link set vn1br master brm

ip link set vn1 netns ns-rt1
ip netns exec ns-rt1 ip addr add 2001:db9:4::2/64 dev vn1

ip netns exec ns-rt1 ip link set vn1 up
```

Is this how a veth network is setup? Do I need multiple bridges or tap interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently I needed to add iptables rules for OSPF.

```
ip6tables -I FORWARD -p 89 -j ACCEPT
```