# bridged virtual networks within namespaces

Tags: networking

I want to obtain next virtual network structure without internet access so far:

```
br0
|
| - vhost1 <  --   > vguest1
| - vhost2 <  --   > vguest2
| - tap
```

vguest1 and vguest2 are in isolated namespace.

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
# because of this, do not run script itself under sudo:
YOUR_USER=$(whoami)

network=192.168.41

down_interface() {
    #  2>/dev/null
    sudo ip link set "$1" down  || true
    sudo ip link delete "$1"  || true
}

setup_tap() {
    #tap:
    sudo ip tuntap add dev "$1" mode tap # user "${YOUR_USER}" group netdev
    sudo ip link set "$1" master $br
    sudo ip link set "$1" up
    # sudo bridge vlan add dev "$1" vid "$2" pvid untagged master
}

setup_veth() {
    sudo ip link add "$1" type veth peer name "$2"
    #sudo ip link set "$1" master $br
    sudo ip -4 addr add "$3" dev "$1"
    sudo ip link set "$1" up
    sudo ip link set "$2" netns guests
    
    sudo ip netns exec guests bash -c "ip -4 addr add $4 dev $2 ; ip link set $2 up"
}

br=br0

sudo ip netns del guests
down_interface tap_emu
down_interface vhost1
down_interface vhost2
down_interface $br

sudo usermod -a -G netdev "${YOUR_USER}"

#bridge:
sudo ip link add name $br type bridge # vlan_filtering 1
sudo ip -4 addr add "$network".1/24 dev $br
sudo ip link set $br up # promisc on arp on 

setup_tap tap_emu 10

# guests namespace:
sudo ip netns add guests
setup_veth vhost1 vguest1 "$network".21/24 "$network".22/24
setup_veth vhost2 vguest2 "$network".23/24 "$network".24/24


ip addr show

ping -c 2 -W 1 -I vhost1 "$network".1
ping -c 2 -W 1 -I vhost2 "$network".1
ping -c 2 -W 1 -I vhost2 "$network".22
ping -c 2 -W 1 -I vhost2 "$network".24
```

During creation, i was guided by
[Howto setup a `veth` virtual network](https://superuser.com/questions/764986/howto-setup-a-veth-virtual-network)
and
https://habr.com/ru/post/549414/

I wonder, why none of pings at the end of script work. What i missed?

Comment: I think you (or maybe your guide) have some misunderstand about veth (or bridging, perhaps). You don't need to / shouldn't assign IP on the "vhosts" (because they are bridge slaves in your case). For similar reason, the `-I` in your ping commands don't really make sense. (You can/should really *just* ping the IPs of the vguests from the "main" netns, and ping the IP of the *bridge* from the guest netns, i.e., with netns exec; only in the latter `-I` might make sense). (Btw, why do you even have two vguests in the same netns?)

Comment: the idea to have pure virtual network with one subnet and two dedicated nodes that reachable each other. But for now they do not even reachable to host/bridge. From namespaces i don't have ping as well either to bridge or veth

Comment: regarding ip's for veth. In 2nd link we have

'# В исходном пространстве имён
$ ip addr add 10.1.1.1/24 dev veth0
$ ip link set dev veth0 up

# В пространстве имён coke
C$ ip addr add 10.1.1.2/24 dev veth1
C$ ip link set dev veth1 up'

So, both sides of veth obtain ip

Comment: What I mean is, the reason you can't ping is that you shouldn't use any of the "vhosts" as the "entry point". It is only correct to use the bridge as that (and you don't even need to specify it with `-I` as the route will make sure it is used).

Comment: Also make sure you "host" does not block icmp with a firewall.